# jquery attr(' selected','selected') for option not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, select, attr

When i change the option in select dropdown,I pass the value selected to that particular option..it works fine in chrome and FF.But it is not working in IE.

I do it by passing
`$('select option').removeAttr('selected');
$(this).attr("selected", "selected");`

I am passing example in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/harshacharya/JyvUm/

I am trying to do something like this:
When an option is selected,it has attribute selected and other option dont.
The above function dont work in IE.

Can you please help me.Thanks.

Comment: You no need to set, `HTML` will automatically take care of removing/adding `selected` to the option

Comment: why do you want to do that

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to see your change in the DOM inspector. IE will not do that by default (and you should not care as the selected values behind-the-scenes are correct).

However, in IE, you can do this by setting the `prop` `defaultSelected` to `"selected"`. You will then see the visual attribute change in the DOM.

```
.prop("defaultSelected", "selected");
```

Note: To remove it from the other elements you need to set the prop to null.

```
$(this).find('option').prop("defaultSelected", null);
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JyvUm/8/